# Find the matrix of the linear transformation $T : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ that projects a vector onto the plane $x − y + 2z = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, projection, projection-matrices

> Find the matrix of the linear transformation $T : \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ that projects a vector onto the plane $x − y + 2z = 0$.

---

I know how to find matrix of linear transformation when projecting onto the xy/xz/yz planes but not sure what to do when then plane is an equation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

An orthonormal basis for your plane $x-y+2z=0$ is given by
$$v_1 = \frac1{\sqrt2}(1,1,0), \quad v_2 = \frac1{\sqrt3}(1,-1,1)$$
so your $T$ is given by $Tx = \langle x,v_1\rangle v_1 + \langle x,v_2\rangle v_2.$

Comment: first of all thank you! would you mind explaining this in a more plain english way?

Comment: @CaptainToad Sure, I found two unit vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ which lie in the plane and are orthogonal to each other. Now how to find the projection of a vector $x$ onto the plane? We project $x$ onto the vector $v_1$ (this is $\langle x,v_1\rangle v_1$) then we project $x$ onto $v_2$ (this is $\langle x,v_2\rangle v_2$) and then we sum up the two projections. If you think about it, this is precisely the same thing you do when projecting to the $xy$-plane, say.

Comment: I am trying my very best to understand but this is very very confusing... Is there a video you know talks about this type of problems? thanks

Comment: @CaptainToad Have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qz3Q3v84k9Y

Comment: Is this what I should be doing? Finding [T] = [T(e1) T(e2) T(e3)] with these steps?

Comment: updated link. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1evmYh7dNvYx2irEkfB_-hmajUvdbLPQs/view?usp=sharing Sorry about the previous one.

Comment: @CaptainToad Yes, I didn't check the calculations but conceptually that's it.

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of an approach slightly ddifferent from mechanoidroid's.

First, note that the vector $v=(1,-1,2)$. is orthogonal to the plane $x-y+2z=0$ (why?).  Next construct a map $P$ that projects onto the line spanned by $v$.  Finally, note that if $T$ is the projection onto the plane, $P+T=I$ (why?), similar to how projection onto the z axis and projection onto the xy-plane add to $I$.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answer. I am still a confused. I have watched a video @mechanodroid suggested and trying to get all the information I got and did this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XQUFB0BSnUXhlfLBfHvGucx7NGsNgNV9/view?usp=sharing Is this what I should be doing? Thanks.

Comment: @CaptainToad Yes, I think that looks approximately right (I didn't check the calculations, but the idea seems correct)

Comment: thank you very much!